# GitHub enterprise error while push the local chnages

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

Getting the following error while pushing the changes from local to github enterprise.

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10/10), completed with 10 local objects.        
remote: Jira-validation-hook.sh: execution exceeded 5s timeout        
To https://github.abc.com/PLK/projectabc.git
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.abc.com/PLK/projectabc.git'
!   refs/heads/SP-121:refs/heads/SP-121 [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
Done
```

Comment: And what's the question? If you want to know what to do about it - contact your github hosting team. The error is pretty clear on what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub Enterprise, it's possible for the administrators to add a pre-receive hook that controls whether data should be allowed or not.  This hook, however, must complete within 5 seconds.

In your server's case, the hook took longer than it was supposed to, and therefore the operation failed, and the push was rejected.  You can try your push again in case the server just happened to be overloaded, but in general, this is something only your GitHub Enterprise administrator can fix.  They'd need to fix their script to take less time when pushes occur, so you should contact them and ask them to do so.